# Como fazer upload de PDF gerado dinamicamente para a o AWS com o Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, amazon-aws, file-upload

Eu estou gerando um *PDF* de forma dinâmica com o `DOMPDF` no *Laravel* e eu tenho que salvar o documento no serviço *Cloud* da *Amazon*.

**Eu não estou conseguindo salvar o documento na nuvem**. Porem só consigo salvar localmente.

```php
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('contract.contract-pdf', $data);
    $pdf->save('contract.pdf');
    $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
    $s3->put('pdf/contract', new File('contract.pdf'), 'public');
```

**Como envia-lo para nuvem?**

Comment: Amigo..deu alguma mensagem de erro? Tem algum erro no log do Laravel? Acredito que este é um caso para uso de TDD. [Escreva um teste unitário, ou teste de integração](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/testing). Teste um envio qualquer para a Amazon, e veja se se as credenciais que você está utilizando tem as corretas permissões. Ou utilize o Tinker do laravel. Ex.: ```php artisan tinker >> \Storage::disk('s3')->put('teste.txt', 'hello')```. Depois veja se no seu bucket existe o arquivo "teste.txt" ou se aparece alguma mensagem de erro. Acho que seu problema é de configuração de permissão na AWS.

Comment: [Solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354437/11584963). Utilizando a função output() do DomPDF para enviar os dados.